# ImageButton turns into black blank on OpenGL ES environment of Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

My camera app's preview is running by `GLSurfaceView` of OpenGL ES 2.0.
There is no errors in logcat. And all functions of the app work correctly. However sometimes `ImageButton` turns into black blank when I switch from rear-facing camera to front-facing camera or adversely.

There are steps for switching between rear-facing and front-facing camera as follows.

-1. destroy `Renderer` object (at customized `Renderer` class)

```
public void onSurfaceDestroyed() {
        ......

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        mSTexture.release();
        mSTexture = null;
        mUpdateST = false;
        pTexCoord = null;
        pVertex = null;
        deleteTexture();

        ......
}
```

-2. destroy camera view (at customized `GLSurfaceView` class)

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.surfaceDestroyed(holder);
        mRenderer.onSurfaceDestroyed();
        mRenderer = null;
        mGestureDetector = null;
        mHandler = null;
}
```

-3. create new camera view (at addCameraView method of `MainActivity`)

```
public void addCameraView() {
        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mWidth, mHeight, mPicSizeR, mPicSizeF, mCameraMode, mFlashMode, mHandler);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        mCameraView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mRootLayout.addView(mCameraView, 0);
}
```

-4. create new `Renderer` object (at constructor of customized `GLSurfaceView` class)

```
public class CameraView extends GLSurfaceView {
        CameraActivity.CameraHandler mHandler;
        CameraRenderer mRenderer;
        GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

        CameraView(Context context, int width, int height, int picSizeR, int picSizeF, boolean camera, int flash, CameraActivity.CameraHandler handler) {
            super(context);

            mHandler = handler;
            mRenderer = new CameraRenderer(this, width, height, picSizeR, picSizeF, camera, flash, handler);
            setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            setRenderer(mRenderer);
            setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        }
        ......
}
```

At first, I assumed the problem is about lack of memory. And... to get more memory, inserted the code `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest file. But, it didn't work.

I don't know what's the problem. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution about this issue. It is to remove `deleteTexture()` in `onSurfaceDestroyed()`. The contents of `deleteTexture()` is as follows.

```
public void deleteTexture() {
    GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, hTex, 0);
}
```

I don't know exactly why calling `GLES20.glDeleteTextures()`, as often as `Renderer` object is destroyed, causes to mess `ImageButton` up. Because I have only few experiences about using OpenGL ES 2.0. I wish that Somebody who knows OpenGL ES very well explain it. :)